# Language selection working locally but not on server

Tags: php, laravel, controller, multilingual

I'm building a multilingual website starting with 2 languages - portuguese and english - and everything works on my local server but not on the actual server.

On the website i have 2 buttons, one for each language, that look like this: 
[image]

The code for the buttons is as follows:

```
<form action="{{ URL::route('language-chooser')  }}" method="post">
    <input id="locale_pt" type="submit" name="locale" class="<?php echo Lang::locale() == 'PT' ? 'active' : ''  ?>" value="PT"/>
    <span>|</span>
    <input id="locale_en" type="submit" name="locale" class="<?php echo Lang::locale() == 'EN' ? 'active' : ''  ?>" value="EN"/>
</form>
```

Then I have a controller that looks like this:

```
class LanguageController extends BaseController {
    public function chooser() {

        Session::set('locale', Input::get('locale'));
        return Redirect::back();

    }
}
```

And finally a route that looks like:

```
Route::post('/language', array(
    'before' => 'csrf',
    'as' => 'language-chooser',
    'uses' => 'LanguageController@chooser'
));
```

Now my problem is, as the title says, everything works perfectly fine on my local server but when I upload it to the actual online server the buttons stop working. I click them, the page reloads, or so it seems, but the language for the site doesnt change. It doesnt throw any errors or anything to help me diagnose the problem, i don't know what else to do.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you.

EDIT: ------------------------------------------------

The server is using PHP 5.4 .

I just did

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"])) {
echo "active";
} else {
echo "don't see one";
}
```

and it echoes "active" so I guess the session is working. Right?

And if i do `<?php echo Lang::locale() ?>` I get the value of the last button I clicked but the language still doesnt change.

EDIT: -----------------------------------------------

Problem solved. It was a case sensitive situation. Thank you to everyone who tried to help.

Comment: What php version are you using on your server

Comment: Have you checked that session is working on server?

Comment: Thread edited with answers to questions in comments. Thank you